NextJs App with Express API - Cookies authentication
I have a Next.js (14 - app router) application that works with an external Express API.
For user authentication, I use http_only cookies. I'm struggling a bit because I would like to use Next.js's server-side features, for example, to pre-load some information on the server side to make it available immediately without loading delays.
The problem is that my cookies are stored in my browser. I created a fetchWrapper that I can run on either the server or the client; if it's on the client, it automatically retransmits the cookies. However, if it's on the server, it takes the cookies and sets them in the header. This works, but I have a discrepancy with the cookies.
For instance, if my access token expires, I will refresh it on my server-side requests and then reload it on the next client request.
I think the logic might not be right.
Do you have any recommendations for managing authentication between Next.js (server and client) and my Express API?
let cookies;
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  cookies = require('next/headers').cookies;
}

type FetchOptions = {
  method?: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';
  headers?: Record<string, string>;
  body?: any;
};

const defaultHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};


async function regenerateToken(): Promise<void> {
    const url = `/auth/refresh`;
    const response = fetchWrapper<{ token: string }>(url, {
        method: 'POST',
  }, true);
  return response;
}

function parseCookies(cookieString) {
  if(!cookieString) return []

  const result = [];
  const cookies = cookieString.split(/,(?=\s*\w+=)/);

  cookies.forEach(cookie => {
    const [nameValue] = cookie.split(';');
    const [name, value] = nameValue.trim().split('=');
    result.push({ name, value });
  });

  return result
}
const cookiesToSend = {}

async function fetchWrapper<T>(url: string, options: FetchOptions = {}, retry: boolean = false, req = null): Promise<T> {
  
  const { method = 'GET', headers = {}, body } = options;
  if (!url.startsWith(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)) {
    url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + url;
  }

  
  if(!process.browser){
    if(!retry){
      const cookieStore = await cookies()
      cookiesToSend.accessToken = cookieStore.get('accessToken')
      cookiesToSend.refreshToken = cookieStore.get('refreshToken')
    }

    defaultHeaders.Cookie = ''
    for(let c in cookiesToSend){
      if(cookiesToSend[c] == undefined) continue
      defaultHeaders.Cookie += `${cookiesToSend[c]?.name}=${cookiesToSend[c]?.value};`
    }
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: { ...defaultHeaders, ...headers },
      body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined,
      cache: 'no-store'
    });

    if(!process.browser){
      const cookiesHeader = response.headers.get('set-cookie')
      const parsedCookies = parseCookies(cookiesHeader);
      parsedCookies.forEach(cookie => {
        cookiesToSend[cookie.name] = { name: cookie.name, value: cookie.value };
      });
    }

    if (!response.ok) {
        const errorMessage = await response.json();
        const error = {
            status: response.status,
            message: errorMessage || 'An error occurred',
        };

        if (error.status === 401 && errorMessage.error_code == "TOKEN_EXPIRED") {
            if(!retry){
                    const responseRegenerate = await regenerateToken();
                    return fetchWrapper(url, options, true);
            }else{
                    if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
                        window.location.href = '/connexion';
                        return Promise.reject(new Error('Redirecting to login...'));
                    } 
            }
            
        }
      throw error;
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
    console.log(error);

  }
}

export default fetchWrapper;


Did you try using middleware for Server-Side Authentication? it  can intercept requests, check authentication, and handle token regeneration if needed
``
